# The mechanism of groupByKey function

Tags: apache-spark

I'm a newbie and try to understand the internal implementation of Spark. I have done a test to see the scaling  behavior of `groupByKey`. Results show that the execution time is independent of core number per node, but I can see the time greatly decreases if I increase the node number.

I know this operation should be bottle-necked on Disk and Network. So the observation of core number per node is because of limited Network and Disk bandwidth? If the answer is yes, will the execution time decrease linearly if I increase the node number since the bandwidth increases linearly? It will be greatly appreciated if anyone explain it according to the implementation of `groupByKey` :)

Comment: Exactly how are you adjusting cores? Virtual machines?

Comment: There're 36 cores in my node. I use 4 executors per node in this test and change cores per executor from 1 to 9 :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking `groupByKey` is limited by:

- Amount of data to be shuffled.
- Size of the aggregated, non-lazy collection of values.
- Subsequent garbage collecting.

Depending on the data distribution and cluster topology you may be able to reduce overall latency by increasing number of nodes but at the end of the day it cannot directly address any of the issues enumerated above. Moreover every key has to be finally processed by a single executor.